# Using Gulp to compile separate scss files into separate css files

Tags: sass, gulp

The below works a treat to compile my style.css, however, I have another file in the same directory called editor-style.scss and would like to compile it as .css (same destination)
I don't know JS and have hacked around with a few suggestions, but it just doesn't like any of my syntaxes.
Could someone put me out of my misery?
many thanks.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return sass('sass/style.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9','opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Apologies if you need to see more of the gulpfile... let me know if this is the case and I will share.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should compile .scss files in sass folder seperately. Inform me if it doesn't work.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('sass/*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9','opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```